# Is there a balancing concept in ansible for creating virtual machines across multiple hosts?

Tags: ansible

I have two hosts and I want to create four virtual machines.  Is there a concept of balancing in ansible, which will create two virtual machines on each host as follows?

HOST1: VM1, VM3, ...

HOST2: VM2, VM4, ...

I know I can specify the host on which a VM is created but this is a little strict as I may add more hosts and many more virtual machines and I'd like a dynamic solution if possible.

The best I can manage is:

```
    with_items:
##    - "{{ groups.production }}"
    - prod-test1
    delegate_to: "{{ groups['control'][1] }}"
```

This is far from ideal though as it requires hard references to host group members and virtual machine items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no generic concept in ansible for doing such things, but possible solutions exist. Somewhat ugly, but this works for me. Given the following inventory `hosts`

```
[control]
server1
server2
server3

[production]
vm1
vm2
vm3
vm4
```

and a playbook `play.yml`

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
  - name: Just loop through a group
    debug:
      msg: 'VM is {{inventory_hostname}} target is {{ansible_host}}'
    delegate_to: '{{ groups["control"][play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) % groups["control"]|length] }}'
```

that is executed with `ansible-playbook -i hosts play.yml -l production` gives the following result:

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [Just loop through a group] ***********************************************
ok: [vm1 -> server1] => {
    "msg": "VM is vm1 target is server1"
}
ok: [vm2 -> server2] => {
    "msg": "VM is vm2 target is server2"
}
ok: [vm3 -> server3] => {
    "msg": "VM is vm3 target is server3"
}
ok: [vm4 -> server1] => {
    "msg": "VM is vm4 target is server1"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
vm1                        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
vm2                        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
vm3                        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
vm4                        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

I think that is what you want. You just have to replace the `debug` task with your desired action.

Other load balancing and roling upgrade scenarios are discussed in the [ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_rolling_upgrade.html).

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I think I'll need to include the '-l production' option in the play somehow as I have a format in scripts etc. that I need to follow.  I run plays based on host groups, in this case control.

    [baremetal]
    host01
    host02
    host03
    host04

    [control]
    host01
    host02

    [compute]
    host03
    host04

    [production]
    prod-test1  ansible_host=1.1.2.241 ansible_gateway=1.1.2.65
    prod-test2  ansible_host=1.1.2.242 ansible_gateway=1.1.2.65

    [staging]

Comment: I tried formatting above to make it more readable but it didn't work; indent 4, correct?

Comment: Adapted above as follows and it's grand, just need to throw my stuff in and should hopefully be good.  Thanks again for the answer.

    - hosts: production
      become_user: root
      gather_facts: False
    
      tasks:
    
      - name: Just loop through a group
        debug:
          msg: 'VM is {{inventory_hostname}} target is {{groups["control"][play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) % groups["control"]|length]}}'
        delegate_to: '{{ groups["control"][play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) % groups["control"]|length] }}'